# Can't connect to Steam using Blueprints in UE4.25

Tags: multiplayer, unreal-4, unreal, blueprints, steam

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngBI40tjirE&list=PLZlv_N0_O1gYqSlbGQVKsRg6fpxWndZqZ&index=11) by Unreal Engine itself, but I don't have a Steam overlay popup like I'm supposed to, (according to the tutorial.) And actually a lot of people have a similar issues like this.

What I have done / tried is:

- Enabling Steam overlay (in Steam settings, but it was already enabled)
- I've already edited the DefaultEngine config file
- I'm playing my game (in Unreal Engine) from the Standalone Game option
- Searching this up, re-watching tutorial, looking at tutorial's comments
- Enabled the Online Subsystem Steam plugin

And I still don't know what the issue is. I've also looked at [this thread](https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/1756040-ue4-4-25-steam-issue/page2) by the Unreal Engine community, but it didn't help that much.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked when I packaged the game. You should try that.

Comment: Do you know why? Maybe there's a code identifier that's only there in the packaged version? So if you do it from editor it says "I'm UE4 Editor and I'm connecting to steam". I'm pretty sure DBD can connect to steam in dev mode, provided the editor is run as -game